# Raspberry Pi as amplifier to connect speaker with TV

Tags: speakers

I have two old (passive) speakers and I was thinking of using a Raspberry Pi to create an amplifier to connect the speakers to my TV. Furthermore it would be nice to connect with my phone via Bluetooth to play music.

I found the [IQaudio DigiAMP+](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/iqaudio-digiamp-plus/) on the official website and I understand that I can use it to connect the speakers to the Raspberry Pi. With the built-in Bluetooth, it should be possible to turn it into a Bluetooth speaker.

But how can I connect the TV to the Raspberry Pi so that it uses the speakers?

The television has a 3.5 mm audio jack for output. Furthermore there're ports for SCART, Component, VGA, VGA audio, S-PDIF, HDMI and USB.

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing is that you need to find out what signal the socket gives (line out or headphones) and find if the adapter can take that level of signal in.  If its designed for headphones then research converting the output signal levels on sites such as [this one](https://www.sweetwater.com/insync/headphone-outputs-used-line-outputs-for-line-level-gear/). Make sure you are 100% confident at this point - you can blow the input stage of the board from high voltage or get nothing out!

If not, you could look to a bluetooth adapter for the signal level - eBay / Amazon have lots.

It's worth looking at every connection on the back of the TV, sometimes SCART / DVI / HDMI / S-PDIF / TOS Optical connectors are hidden and they can give better and simpler results.

My current 'go-to' music player is [Volumio](https://volumio.org) and it takes bluetooth and audio-in as options (along with lots of others) and can play music files on the internal SD-Card, HDD / SDD via USB etc.  It has a basic app (iOS and Android) that is used to fund development but can be used FOC via the web interface.

You will need to check if the board works with this software - I2S is the common standard for Pi to music players.

Check the board can drive your speakers and you have a good clean power supply.

Comment: I added all available ports to my question.

It looks like a normal headphone port but the IQaudio DigiAMP+ only has ports for the speakers. So I don't know what to do with the cable from the TV.

Comment: I was wondering, if I need something like the "IQaudio DAC Pro". But I'm not sure, if the 3.5 mm port is for input or output.

Comment: @foodev Page 4 of https://datasheets.raspberrypi.org/iqaudio/iqaudio-product-brief.pdf shows headphone so its output (Headphones: 3.5mm jack socket). Look at using the TV S/PDIF output but check the HAT as the correct connector (RCA vs TOSLINK) and can drive your speakers.

Comment: Thanks for the help but how can I connect the S/PDIF to the Raspberry Pi? The HAT only has output ports as far as I know. Or do I have to use the I²S?

Comment: You need to buy a HAT with the correct connectors to match what you are outputting from the TV. The Pi uses I2S to output sound from Bluetooth /  file playback and control the HAT (input source / volume)  Output from the TV would be looped through the HAT to the speakers with volume control on the Pi via I2S.

Comment: So should something like the [HiFiBerry DAC+ ADC](https://www.hifiberry.com/shop/boards/hifiberry-dac-adc/) work? It has a 3.5 mm jack for input ([datasheet](https://www.hifiberry.com/docs/data-sheets/datasheet-dac-adc/)). Or rather the [HiFiBerry Digi+ I/O](https://www.hifiberry.com/shop/boards/hifiberry-digi-io/)?

Comment: @foodev Best to contact them with your TV output details - I've not used either HAT.